# How to change the colour of a string when binding to a label in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 text boxes in which the user enters values and clicks a button.When the button is clicked I want to replace the value in the first box with to the second box and show it in a label.

I want to show the replaced value in a colour format so that the user can identify it easily.

So how can a string can be colour formatted, I want to colour the string not the label

**For eg:**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
string value1 = "Hi! This is a demo code";
lblName.Text = value1.Replace("demo", "sample");
```

Now my label shows me **"Hi! This is a sample code"**

There I want only the `sample` to be coloured and rest be same as a normal `label` text be

Comment: You do that via applying styles to an HTML element (such as a span) that surrounds the text you want to change the color of.

Comment: Can I have a piece of code @mason

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it would be to wrap the replacement text in a span with an associated style or css class:

```
lblName.Text = value1.Replace("demo", "<span style='color: red;'>sample</span>"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you've already got the code to set the label visible, it's contents, and hide the textbox... if you label element looks something like:

```
<span runat="server" id="label1" />
```

After populating it you could just:

```
label1.Style.Value = "color:red;";
```

OR

```
label1.Style.Add("color", "red");
```

Comment: I don't want to colour everything in the label, just a part of it @Sgr3005

Comment: Then you need to split the label.  The part you want colored has to be its own element.  Can you show me what you have now?  I could envision something like: <span id="setMeVisible" runat="server">Here is my Text: <span runat="server" id="label1" /></span>  But if that's the case just put the style attribute directly in the inner span.

Comment: Nice. For the record, the "EG" part of the was not in the OP when I tried to help.  No good deed goes unpunished.