# How to change color in part of string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, colors, draw

I need to change a color in part of string. How to do this ?

```
if (kmTotalMil < allTotal || kmTotalMil > allTotal)
{
    return "You are " + kmTotalMil.ToString() + " km." + " in city " + allTotal.ToString() + " km.";
}
```

I need **kmTotalMil.ToString()** and **allTotal.ToString()** must be a RED color.

How to do this ?

Comment: Strings don't have colors, they are just character arrays. Please explain how this string will be displayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178249/how-to-highlight-or-change-the-color-of-some-words-in-a-label-dynamically-at-run, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706385/how-to-change-the-colour-of-a-string-when-binding-to-a-label-in-asp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are asking this for asp.net sites you should use [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) to style the text:

```
if (kmTotalMil < allTotal || kmTotalMil > allTotal)
{
    return "You are <span style='color:red'>" + kmTotalMil.ToString() + "</span> km." + " in city <span style='color:red'>" + allTotal.ToString() + "</span> km.";
}
```

Here is the same result with string.Format:

```
if (kmTotalMil < allTotal || kmTotalMil > allTotal)
{
    return string.Format("You are <span style='color:red'>{0}</span> km. in city <span style='color:red'>{1}</span> km.", kmTotalMil, allTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're outputting this to html, in which case you'll need to use [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) to style your string. In the code below I'm returning a string which includes a HTML tag, span in this case, and I've added some inline styling with a css rule to change the color to red:

```
if (kmTotalMil < allTotal || kmTotalMil > allTotal)
{
    return "<span style='color:red'>some text</span>";
}
```

I would suggest you to go through some tutorials on [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) and string concatenation in C# as your next step.